# Error running revit addin with Design Automation for Revit - Local debug tool

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-designautomation

I am trying to run an addin for design automation locally by following the tutorial: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/design-automation-debug-revit-plugin-locally

Running the addin from visual studio i'm getting this FatalExecutionEngineError exception
[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EB88w.png)

From Revit usign the DesignAutomationEventHandler i'm getting this "There is no Unicode byte order mark" error
[DesignAutomationEventHandler error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tkj5Y.png)

I tried reinstalling and the problem persists

Comment: There is not much information here to be able to help you. You may update your post with some code / API call that you think is throwing an exception.

Comment: The problem happens before executing the code of my addin, when I am executing it from visual studio, the exception FatalExecutionEngineError is thrown and Revit closes before I can try to execute the addin through the external tool DesignAutomationHandler

Comment: What's your Revit version running the local debug tool? I happened to see the same issue on my side with Revit 2023 yesterday. That error was caused by the incorrect addin content in the XML header. I manually fixed the header from `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="yes"?>` to `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>` in the `C:\ProgramData\Autodesk\Revit\Addins\2023\Autodesk.RobotStructuralAnalysysLink.Application.addin`.